# Json string mutating

Tags: android, vb.net, wcf, rest

I have a .Net WCF Rest service returning Json to be consumed by an Android app.

In debug, the WCF service correctly has the return value (Json) as:

```
{"BaseLoyaltyPoints":1480,"BonusLoyaltyPoints":0,"BrandId":1414, [etc...] }
```

Also in debug, when it returns to Notepad, the return value has changed to:

```
{\"BaseLoyaltyPoints\":1480,\"BonusLoyaltyPoints\":0,\"BrandId\":1414, [etc...] }
```

And when it gets to my Android app, it has become:

```
{\\"BaseLoyaltyPoints\\":1480,\\"BonusLoyaltyPoints\\":0,\\"BrandId\\":1414, [etc...] }
```

This is the boilerplate code I am using to serialize the Json:

```
Dim stream1 As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream
Dim ser As DataContractJsonSerializer = New DataContractJsonSerializer(GetType(FullProduct))
ser.WriteObject(stream1, Me)

Dim _json As String = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream1.ToArray())
stream1.Close()
```

The Android code to get the Json is:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(getString(R.string.CONST_RestService) + "/json/Product/" + productID);
ResponseHandler<String> handler = new BasicResponseHandler();       
result = httpclient.execute(request, handler);  
jObject = new JSONObject(result);
```

What's going on?

Thanks

Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON Data needs to be an evaluable JavaScript String - the " character needs to be escaped to \" (the character " as opposed to the String limitor "), and the \ in that expression needs to be escaped as well (because \ also is a special character). So it has been that string all along, it was just printed differently everytime.

Take this JavaScript for an example:

```
object = JSON.parse("{\"hello\":\"World\"}");
alert(object.hello);
```

The following is more of a guess than actual knowledge, because I do not know how exactly the classes you used behave, but I think that it's about right.

As you can see, the `"` characters need to be escaped to `\"`, so your .NET JSON serializer does just that. Everything is fine, interpreting this as JS would work as expected.

Now what is *probably* going on is that your JSONObject constructor does not expect Strings to be already properly escaped, so it does that itself. To clarify: When you say "with one escape character", you probably mean something like this:

```
String workingJSONString = "{\"Hello\":\"World\"}"
```

right? The problem here is that Java has the same escaping rules as JavaScript - this is not what you get from your HTTPRequest, what you get is

```
String youGotThis = "{\\\"Hello\\\":\\\"World\\\"}"
```

Because there are literal backslashes in your String, and those need to be escaped as well. I am pretty certain that that is what is going on, and you'd probably either have to tell your .NET JSON serializer not to apply escape rules or find something that constructs a JSONObject from a properly escaped JSON string - or remove the unnecessary escapes yourself.

I hope this helped - but again, I am not fully certain so you should just check out if it actually behaves as I said.

Comment: If I feed Android with a static string of the Json with just the one escape character, it handles it. The string with the 2 escape characters causes it to fail. My query is, where are these 2 escape characters coming from, and if it has to be that way, what changes do I need to make to the Android code to handle it?

Comment: ... Or rather, why is Android throwing a Json exception at jObject = new JSONObject(result); ?

Comment: Thanks Cubic. I understand what you're saying, and that does seem to be the case. I changed .net default serializer to Newtonsoft and got the same result. Am looking for something to replace the Android built in json parser. Suprised that no-one else is having the same problem as me. Thanks anyway.